# Smallest value in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, education

Given the beginning of a sequence: 59, 106, 37, 58, 89, 145.. find the smallest possible value of this sequence. 
I know that the answer is '4', but can someone please explain what the rule for this sequence is?
thanks!

Comment: Why the [tag:education] tag?  What does it have to do with education?

Comment: Although the answer below is very clever, this question is a little misleading. Given a set of finitely many initial values we can have infinitely many different sequences and different rules.

Answer (score 2):

Take the sum of the square of the previous number's digits.  Once you reach a four it repeats: $4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4$